# List files on SFTP server within Docker

Tags: java, sftp

I'm trying to access files directly from an SFTP server, using Docker.

The following works:

```
import static java.nio.file.Paths.get;

public File[] copyExtractFiles() {
    String command = "sftp -i case-loader/./docker/config -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -P 2222 sftp@localhost:incoming/*.xml src/test/resources/extract";

    Process p = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", command).start();
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader stdOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), Charset.forName(CHARSET_NAME)));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream(), Charset.forName(CHARSET_NAME)));

    return get("src/test/resources/extract").toFile().listFiles();

}
```

This transfers an XML file from the `incoming` directory on the Docker image to the `src/test/resources/extract` directory, and then lists the files.

However, I do not have access to the local file system and so want to access the files directly on the SFTP server. Is this possible? What do I need to change?

Comment: if you have sftp probably you also have ssh/scp. Use them to write on the remote.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the question. But, what does Docker have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use SFTP library, like JSch, instead of driving an external console application. Then you will be able to download the file list to memory.

[Java - download from SFTP directly to memory without ever writing to file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32900090/850848).